# I cannot figure out how to make ListView work properly

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to render a list in React Native, however, nothing ever shows. I am logging the list before render as well and it is showing that the data field is being populated, but nothing is being shown.

[This is the ListView code that I am trying that is NOT working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0O4uU.png)

[This is the way that I am currently rendering the list. This method is working for me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCdhL.png)

The reason that I want to use ListView instead of the current method that I am using is because I was reading from the documentation that ListView has better properties and performance.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try destructuring correctly your item in renderItem. I mean:

```
  <FlatList 
    data={this.state.users}
    renderItem={({item}) => {
      return (
        <View>
          <Image source={{uri: item.image}} style={{width: 150, height: 150}} />
          <Text>{item.login}</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }}
    keyExtractor={(user) => user.id}
  />
```

Or, if you prefer to call it as `info`, define a function:

```
  renderItem = (info) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image source={{uri: info.image}} style={{width: 150, height: 150}} />
        <Text>{info.login}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

And call it like

```
  <FlatList 
    data={this.state.users}
    renderItem={({item}) => this.renderItem(item)}
    keyExtractor={(user) => user.id}
  />
```

See more [in the offical doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#renderitem)

Comment: Milore, thanks for the in-depth reply. I tried both methods that you suggested and nothing is showing. This is the method I tried earlier until I figured out about the mapping method that was in my post. Do I need to map out the array in the data first?

Comment: Uhm, I was sure curly brackets would have worked... What do you mean with 'map out the array in the data'?

Comment: Because my array of users is an array of objects. With the method I used that is working, that array is being mapped out and then being used. However, in the data tag it is just trying to use the array of objects. I'm not sure. I've been trying to get ListView to work for a while now and it just doesn't seem to work. But when I use the "this.state.users.map(user)" method, it shows the data, so I know the data is there, but it is just not being displayed properly.

Comment: Can you try to place a console.log(item) in the renderItem prop of the first method I wrote?

Comment: Sure! I tried to console.log(info) in the renderItem function (tried both before the render and after the render) via the second method you tried. Didn't get a log. I then tried your first method and same thing; no logs.

Comment: It sounds so strange to me. Is you item.id field a string? Otherwise can you try to cast it with .toString() in your keyExtractor?

Comment: My last suggestion is to try with a different keyExtractor, like keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}

Comment: I found the issue. I ended up adding the extraData property. I believe that this fixed it because the data was being loaded async before a render, and so it wasn't re-rendering after the data was loaded. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Nice man, I had to imagine that data were dynamically loaded, my bad!

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the item property from your data property in the FlatList

```
<FlatList 
    data={this.state.users}
    renderItem={({item}) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image source={{uri: item.image}} style={{width: 150, height: 150}} />
        <Text>{item.login}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }}
  keyExtractor={(user) => user.id}
/>
```

> Note **{item}** in the renderItem callback

***Another example***

```
<FlatList 
    data={this.state.users}
    renderItem={(data) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image source={{uri: data.item.image}} style={{width: 150, height: 150}} />
        <Text>{data.item.login}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }}
  keyExtractor={(user) => user.id}
/>
```